# Specification Document

Tags: databases, documents

I have been asked to research on a certain database then write down a specification document which covers Authentication, Authorization and Encryption. Has anyone ever come across such a documentation? I need to know if there is an example I can borrow from.

Comment: What have you done yourself to research the problem? Please share with us some of your findings.

Comment: I have not found standard method of doing it so far. I am currently just putting in every topic that seems important.